# networkx keyerror due to "long" format

Tags: networkx, graphml

I am getting an error:

**KeyError: 'long'**

when I run this code:

```
import networkx as nx
graph_input = open("final_graphml_train/myhead.txt", mode='rb')
graph = nx.read_graphml(graph_input)
```

The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key id="d20" for="edge" attr.name="key" attr.type="long" />
</graphml>
```

I have checked the documentation that allows the "long" format.

http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd

> key.type.type is a restriction of xs:NMTOKEN Allowed values: boolean,
> int, long, float, double, string.

How do I avoid the keyerror in networkx?

Comment: What networkx version are you using? Try upgrading it. I checked, in version 2.5. long was not a supported type.

Comment: pip install --upgrade networkx[default] I used this command and it is working. Can you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to the newest version of networkx, it is working as of networkx version 2.6.2.

```
pip install networkx --upgrade
```